# Mocking the Controller's method for testing the view layer

Tags: controller, mocking, playframework

I want to test a **view layer**.

I have a Controller with method

```
class Controller ... {
public void do() {

  List<String> data = ....

  render(data);
}
..
}
```

I have web-driver test (functional tests) that test that **data able to be shown** as a list on the page.

So, how can I mock the do() method in PlayFramework's controller, in order to not depend on real data that is fetching from somewhere? What is the common approach? How play would know/use this controller's method if it is mocked in some particular test..?

-- added after having got some comments (thx):

I just want to test a view when controller would return some data back to it.

But my controller's logic is not ready yet, I just know that It will return List of < String > and in the view, I need to show this Strings in < li > html elements. That's it.

I do not know nothing - how I would implement my Controller, where it would use database or webservices to return data back to the view (that why I can Not mock anything inside my controller.. let's say Http.get().. or Database.get() )..

- I do not know yet how I would implement my controller, I now what it would return - nevertheless, for the view it does not matter how controller does its work - view just show these data, and I want to test that - whether it able to show any data like a list in html.

Answer (score 3):

Build an interface to with a method to get your data.

```
public interface DataProvider {
    public List<String> getData();
}
```

For testing you can implement this interface with a class providing some test values.

```
public class MockDataProvider implements DataProvider {
    public List<String> getData() {
        String[] testData = {"a","b","c"};
        return Arrays.asList(testData);
    }
}
```

Later on when you know from where you fetch your data (database, web-request, whatever) you just implement your interface again.

```
public class WebProvider implements DataProvider {
    public List<String> getData() {
        ... WS.url("http://service.example.com").get();
        // fetch the data
        return dataList;
    }
}
```

And in you controller you can switch whether you are in test-mode or not.

```
class MyController ... {
    public static void datalist() {
        DataProvider provider;

        if (Play.runingInTestMode()) {
            provider = new MockDataProvider();
        } else {
            provider = new WebProvider();
        }

        List<String> data = provider.getData();
        render(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know nothing of PlayFramework but this is a common question that arises when unit testing MVC. In general you have your 'functional' or integration tests that test whether the whole thing works and unit tests for your models. Aside from wanting 100% code coverage, you need to ask yourself whether you actually need to test this code.

If you decide that you do, then I would look to refactor your function to use dependecy injection to inject a mock object into the function you want to test. But if you have to do a load of refactoring to unit test code that will be covered by your integration testing, then is it really needed?

Comment: I have added some explanation up there in my description. (Thx for reply, anyway)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test your view layer, use Selenium.
It's provided by Play.

Also, you can use a special database build for tests.

Don't try to mock the controller : use a in-memory database (very fast) and load data in it for your tests.

*Add after your update :*

Maybe you could hardcode a list until you develop the controller.